# JOI - forcing required via requiredKeys

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I a have base userSchema like this:

```
const userSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    firstName: Joi.string(),
    lastName: Joi.string(),
    email: Joi.string().email(),
    username: username,
    password: password,
    devices: Joi.array().items(userDevicesSchema),
    billing: userBillingSchema,
    clients: Joi.array().items(userClientSchema),
    cart: Joi.array().items(userCartSchema),
    orders: Joi.array().items(userOrderScherma),
    isAdmin: Joi.boolean(),
    isActive: Joi.boolean(),
    lang: Joi.string().valid(['cs', 'de', 'en', 'es', 'fr', 'ja']),
    credit: Joi.number(),
    timeZone: Joi.string().timeZone(),
    customization: userCustomizationSchema,
    level: Joi.string().valid(['casual', 'scout', 'explorer', 'integrator']),
    microservicesAccess: Joi.array().items(Joi.string())
}).options({ abortEarly: false, stripUnknown: true });
```

Now I want to create a userSignupSchema for Signup API validation. I need to set some fields to be required. I tried this:

```
const userSignupSchema = userSchema
        .requiredKeys('firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'lang', 'level', 'timeZone', 'level')
        .forbiddenKeys('devices', 'cart', 'orders', 'isAdmin', 'credit', 'microservicesAccess' );
```

But I get error: "unknown key(s) level". The forbidden keys work perfectly. Does anybody has a working example of using requiredKeys? I was not able to find any...

Comment: Did you try it without the array `[]` around the keys?

Comment: Yes, I tried...I do not know what I am doing wrong here because it really works well for forbiddenKeys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb...I was interpreting the word "level" in the error message as some hierarchy level issue but it was the name of one of schema attribute...I had multiple "level" in requiredKeys. Fixed after several hours of searching the internet...